# How to customize an application which is console?

Tags: winforms, customization, remoting

Sorry for the bad English. I'm new to C# and trying to develop an application that manages and controls some other console applications.
It gets console apps as **Process.MainWindowHandle** for input.
But what I need to know is: How can I change their **Console.BackgroundColor** property?
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way for communication between processes. However there are some options for doing that

- [Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)
- [Reading from a common file and use FileWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)
- Using MSMQ
- [Using WCF using NetNamedPipeBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding(v=vs.110).aspx)